# How to make my first recorded script repeat automatic to the next windows tab or web browser with one key storkes

Tags: browser, tabs, web, repeater

Yes I mean web browsers,.. I also used ctrl + tab to navigate between windows tab or web browser... however I sometimes open up to 10 tabs for inputting the same information over and over again, therefore it will be advantage to me if I can make the recorded script like I showen u above for the first tab to repeat automatically for the rest of the 10 tabs.... this repetition of inputting information will be done normally up to 30 items.. so it means I have to repeat it like 3 cycles.. however the references no. will always changed for the next groups of Tasks, thats why if you notice I put in under variable so that I can change the variable as per assign task.... I mean for example Task 1 got like 30 items, and Task 2- 50 item. Task 3 - 25, Task 4 - 15 Task 5- 60 items.. and so on.. this I so called it "Task" is like a works task and my duty is to assign to references no. date started date approve and date completed and so on for all the task and this is never ending story... so as my humble request I just want to know what is the correct syntax or command so that I can make my recorded scripts for my first tab to repeat automatically to the next tabs (or web browser) with one or two assign key strokes.. my initial key stroke is Ctrl + Alt + k.. however as a said I only manage to make run on the first web browser... maybe I am so lazy to press the ctrl + tab and repeat again the Ctrl + ALt + k over and over again up to 10 times.. Pls help me...  Thanks very much  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to toggle between browser tab then you can use toggle tab addon which shift from one tab to another in specified time period.